# Recognizing sections up to isotopy

Tags: reference-request, dg.differential-geometry, differential-topology, h-principle

Let $E$, $B$ be smooth manifolds, $\pi\colon E\to B$ be a smooth fiber bundle, and $h:B\to E$ be a smooth embedding. I would like to learn what is known about the following

**Question.** When does there exist an isotopy from $h$ to a section of $\pi$?

A necessary condition for the existence of such an isotopy is that $h$ be homotopic to a section of $\pi$. Are there invariants that can be used to show that an isotopy does not exist even when a homotopy exists?

I am mainly interested in the special case that $B$ is a closed manifold, $E = B\times \mathbb{R}$, and $\pi:(b,t)\mapsto b$ is the trivial bundle. I would be grateful to learn about this special case or the general case above.

Comment: An example where such an embedded isotopy doesn't exist can be constructed from inertial h-cobordisms, i.e. nontrivial h-cobordisms which start and end at $M$. Suppose $M \xrightarrow{i_1} H \xleftarrow{i_2} M$ is an inertial h-cobordism. Embed $H$ into $M \times [0,1]$ via $j$ so that $j \circ i_1$ is the inclusion $M \times \{0\} \rightarrow M \times [0,1]$. Then $j \circ i_2$ is homotopic to a section, but there cannot be an embedded isotopy which terminates in a section because that would imply that the h-cobrdism was trivial. I'm not sure if this example also contradicts plain isotopy.

Comment: Obstruction 1: The bundle needs to have a section.  Obstruction theory gives you a tool to find these, or determine if one does not exist.  For example, the Hopf fibration $S^3 \to S^2$ does not have a section.

Comment: You get isotopy for free if your homotopy lives in the space of sections.  But presumably you are interested in free homotopies and not homotopies in the space of sections.  But the question of having a homotopy in the space of sections would be a good partial answer, which you could also approach with obstruction theory.

Comment: Your embedding $h$ needs to have (homological) intersection number $1$ with every fiber.

Comment: @ConnorMalin interesting - what is an "embedded isotopy"?

Comment: @RyanBudney thank you for your help. I did indeed mean free homotopies like you said. In my situation of interest I know that a free homotopy exists, but I was hoping that there still might be some "computable" way of ruling out existence of an isotopy. On the other hand, for the special case $E = B\times \mathbb{R}$ mentioned in my question, it seems that for $\dim(B)\geq 5$ the $s$-cobordism theorem provides necessary and sufficient conditions for the existence of an isotopy, but I don't know how "computable" those conditions are.

Comment: @MarkGrant thank you for your help. That is indeed a condition I have been thinking about, but I believe it is implied by the existence of a free homotopy from $h$ to a section of $\pi$. I was hoping that there might be some "computable" way of ruling out existence of an isotopy even when such a free homotopy exists. I was actually wondering whether this could be achieved using some fancier intersection number (e.g. of submanifolds of some jet bundle) than the one you described, but maybe that isn't possible? The $s$-cobordism theorem also seems relevant - see my reply to Ryan Budney.

Comment: An embedded isotopy is an embedding $i:M \times [0,1] \rightarrow N$, notably it gives an isotopy between $i_0$ and $i_1$. This is stronger than the usual notion of isotopy.

Answer (score 3):

I guess that by "isotopy" you mean isotopy of embeddings.

If $B$ is the $n$-sphere and $E=B\times R$ then your question is equivalent
to the $(n+1)$-dimensional Schönfliess theorem: known for $n\neq 3$,
and a big open question for $n=3$.

To answer your complementary question: if there is a self-diffeomorphism $f$ of $R^{n+1}$ sending
the unit sphere $S^n\subset R^{n+1}$ to your embedded sphere $h(S^n)$, then you can always arrange that $f$ is isotopic to the identity (with compact support). Indeed, you can first arrange that $f$ is orientation-preserving; hence $f$ restricted to the unit ball $B^{n+1}$ is an orientation-preserving embedding of the ball; and such an embedding is necessarily isotopic to the inclusion, by the "Alexander trick" (shrinking the ball to its center).